# can't maximize or toggle chatbox, autoscroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My chatbox won't maximize, autoscroll or return to bottom  for new input. and also, is there any way to make the popup avatar act as android facebook messenger app, with onclick function to minimize and maximize? any help will really be appreciated here. thanks in advance.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>chatbox</title>
    <style>
    .popup-wrap {
        top: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 80px;
        height: 110px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 40px;
    }
    .popup-avatar {
        top: 11px;
        left: 11px;
        background: url(../images/ella1.jpg);
        position: absolute;
        height: 78px;
        width: 78px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-radius:45px 45px 45px 45px
    }
    .shell-1 {
        right: 20px;
        background: #583983;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;  
        border-radius:45px 45px 45px 45px
    }
    .shell-2 {
        background: white;
        height: 78px;
        width: 78px;
        padding: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
        margin: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;  
        border-radius:45px 45px 45px 45px
    }
    .tinyBanner {
        background: #583983;
        color: white;
        height: 24px;
        width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:5px;
        border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    .msgbox_wrap {
        background:white;
        width:250px;
        height:400px;
        position:fixed;
        right:20px;
        padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
        bottom:0px;
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
        border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    }
    .msgbox_wrap-on {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .msg_head{
        cursor:pointer;
        background:#583983;
        padding:15px;
        color:white;
        bottom:0px;
        border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px; 
    }
    .close{
        float:right;
        color:white;
    }
    .msg_wrap{
        background:url(../images/m3-act.jpg);
        min-width:250px;
        height:355px    
    }
    .chatlog {
      height:300px;
    }
    .botMessage {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        position: relative;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  
        border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

    .userMessage {
        background-color:#583983;
        position: relative;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;  
        border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }


    .convo {
        height: 290px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #eeeeee;
    }

    .scroll {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .msg_input {
        background:#583983;     
        height: 42px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #eeeeee;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="popup-wrap">
      <a href="#" id="addClass">
      <div class="shell-1">
        <div class="shell-2">
          <div class="popup-avatar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
      <div class="tinyBanner">Talk to Ella</div>
    </div>
         <div class="msgbox_wrap" id="qnimate">
            <div class="msg_head">Talk to Ella
                <div class="close">X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_wrap">
                <div class="convo scroll">
              <div id="chatlog"></div>
            </div>
    <div class="msg_input">
             <form method="post" name="talkform" id="talkform" action="index.php">
                <form id="talkform" class="talkform">
                    <input id="say" name="say" placeholder="You say...." type="text"   style="background:  #white; height: 41px; width: 237px; font-color: #B1B1B1; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;  border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                </form>
            </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
        </div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // This minimize and close 
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.msg_head').click(function(){
        $('.msgbox_wrap').animate({height:45},'slow');
}); 
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.msgbox_wrap').hide();   
    }); 
});


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //popup chat fromm avatar icon
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addClass").click(function () {
          $('#qnimate').addClass('msgbox_wrap-on');
            });
  });
 </script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//This autoscrolls
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.msg_wrap').load('convo scroll');
        $('#chatlog').animate({scrollTop: $('msg_wrap')[0]}, 1000);
    });
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code animates the chat box back to full height. You set it to `45px` and never do anything else.

```
$('.msgbox_wrap').animate({height:200},'slow');
```